# Incorrect syntax when filtering ng-options?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to sort alphabetically by the 'long_name'. To no avail. I can't do anything to get the list to change. Am I missing something?

```
<select ng-model="client.primary_contact" 
    ng-options="provider.long_name for provider in providers | orderBy:'provider.long_name' track by provider.uid"></select>
```

I started [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) (angular docs on orderBy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide only property name to `orderBy` filter. Try this:

```
ng-options="provider.long_name for provider in providers | orderBy:'long_name' track by provider.uid"
```

Check documentation about [`orderBy`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) filter, especially expression argument.

Comment: although I don't understand what you mean by 'you should only provide property name to 'sortBy' filter.' What are we passing it then?

Comment: I meant that `sortBy` is a function that will be invoked on `providers` array, and this array will be sorted by whatever you tell it to sort. In your original code you said: sort array of objects by property named `provider.long_name`. There is no such property. But there is property named `long_name`.

Comment: @Blackhole Ops, of course. Thank you for correction!